# Why Form->file() doesn't show validation errors?

Tags: forms, validation, cakephp

I got this, which doesn't print validation errors:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->file('fileurl_file', array('label' => '', 'class' => 'input-text')); ?>
```

If I change it to

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('fileurl_file', array('label' => '', 'class' => 'input-text')); ?>
```

It shows validation errors.

Am I doing something wrong?
Thx!

**EDITED:**
I took a look intro the FormHelper class and I saw that even if there is a "file" method it is not implemented in doesn't provide support for printing error if catched any.
Then I saw that the "input" method gets at some point as parameter a "type" (I guess this is mentioned in the documentation too, but I didn't get to read it all) which can be from 'text', 'file', 'select'...
So, this is how I managed to get my file imput work as I needed:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('fileurl_file', array('type' => 'file', 'label' => '', 'class' => 'input-text')); ?>
```

Comment: Can you show the `$this->Form->create` code of form and how you made the validation inside Model?

Comment: <?php echo $this->Form->create('Meta', array('class' => 'form-default section', 'method' => 'post', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')); ?>

Comment: This is the create(), and the validation is done inside a BehaviourModel, but it is not very important because as I said, the difference between working and not working (display errors) is creating an text/file input.

Answer (score 1):

validation is working

FormHelper::input does a lot of work, including output of validation errors.

FormHelper::file only outputs a file, nothing more. You have to output the error yourself

using

```
  <?php echo $this->Form->file('fileurl_file', array('label' => '', 'class' => 'input-text')); 
  echo $this->Form->error('fileurl_file');
  ?>
```

i hope it'll work for you.